# A nebulous who am I riddle

Tags: riddle

There are many who wear me
I protect them from harm
Others say I'm lucky
And use me for charm
I can cause an attraction
Of a physical sort
While some folks will throw me
For amusement and sport

Who am I - can you guess?
I'm so much like you
You'll nail it, for sure
If you think this one through

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are a

> horseshoe

There are many who wear me
I protect them from harm

> they are horses

Others say I'm lucky
And use me for charm

> it is a symbol of luck

I can cause an attraction
Of a physical sort

> A horseshoe shaped magnet

While some folks will throw me
For amusement and sport

> Throwing horseshoes onto pegs, I don't know the exact name

You'll nail it, for sure

> A reference to the nails with which the horseshoe is attached to the hoof

Update, two last clues (after comment)

I'm so much like you

> the letter U

Nebulous (I had to google that one, hope it counts)

> Horseshoe Nebula, a celestial object